# Zapier - How to Send Videos Daily up to 2 Weeks

Tags: zapier

I am using multiple platforms to run a business. I provide 14 tutorial videos to my users after they create an account. What I want is when user sign up, my system should send 1 video / day to that user. Like this

```
video 1  on day 1
video 2 on day 2
...
...
video 14 on day 14
```

I want to make a setup in zapier to do that. Zapier should send each video a day unto 14 days a user gets registered.
Can anyone guide me how I can Achieve that target?

Comment: Send via email or any other way?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible with Zapier, but will use a lot of steps + tasks. You could make a many-stepped zap that is structured like:

1. New User trigger
2. Delay until "tomorrow" (Zapier translates this into the correct date at runtime)
3. Send email w/ video 1
4. Delay until "2 days"
5. Send email w/ video 2
6. etc...

This will work, but probably be too expensive (that's a lot of Zapier tasks). Instead, look into drip email campaigns from any of the popular mail-sending services (such as Mailchimp).